# C# 3.0 Func/OrderBy type inference

Tags: c#, lambda, type-inference

So odd situation that I ran into today with OrderBy:

```
Func<SomeClass, int> orderByNumber = 
  currentClass => 
   currentClass.SomeNumber;
```

Then:

```
someCollection.OrderBy(orderByNumber);
```

This is fine, but I was going to create a method instead because it might be usable somewhere else other than an orderBy.

```
private int ReturnNumber(SomeClass currentClass)
{
  return currentClass.SomeNumber;
}
```

Now when I try to plug that into the OrderBy:

```
someCollection.OrderBy(ReturnNumber);
```

It can't infer the type like it can if I use a Func.  Seems like to me they should be the same since the method itself is "strongly typed" like the Func.

Side Note: I realize I can do this:

```
Func<SomeClass, int> orderByNumber = ReturnNumber;
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This could also be related to ["return-type type inference" not working on Method Groups](http://blogs.msdn.com/ericlippert/archive/2007/11/05/c-3-0-return-type-inference-does-not-work-on-member-groups.aspx).

Essentially, in cases (like `Where`'s predicate) where the generic parameters are only in input positions, method group conversion works fine. But in cases where the generic parameter is a return type (like `Select` or `OrderBy` projections), the compiler won't infer the appropriate delegate conversion.

Answer (score 8):

`ReturnNumber` is *not* a method - instead, it represents a method group containing *all* methods with the name `ReturnNumber` but with potentially different arity-and-type signatures. There are some technical issues with figuring out which method in that method group you actually want in a very generic and works-every-time way. Obviously, the compiler *could* figure it out some, even most, of the time, but a decision was made that putting an algorithm into the compiler which would work only half the time was a bad idea.

The following works, however:

```
someCollection.OrderBy(new Func<SomeClass, int>(ReturnNumber))
```

Comment: Method group is something I wasn't thinking about.  Wish I could mark two answers.